# Why is this expression having a parameter mismatch

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

```
=FormatDateTime(DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, Now()), DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

I get an error stating "The property ‘DefaultValue’ of report parameter ‘MIN_DATE’ doesn't have the expected type. (rsParameterPropertyTypeMismatch)"

Comment: What's the data type of the report parameter MIN_DATE?

Comment: The Date/Time datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormatDateTime returns a string that represents the date, if you have the parameter set its data type to DateTime it will throw this error, you can either change the parameter datatype to string or you can just use

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, Now())
```

Comment: I wanted to get the date with no time, but the text data type helped so thanks.